# Laravel filament multiple dashboards in the same account

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

In the same 'user', after authentication, I want to have a page with a select dropdown where different 'partners' can be chosen, and then a dashboard showing the specific data of the chosen account.

im usign laravel and filament

I'm thinking of filtering the data depending on the selected partner, but I'm not sure how to maintain consistency in the rest of the dashboard. In my database, I already have the 'partners' table established, and the other data depends on it.